# What is http://www.qandasystem.info/ about?

Tags: discussion

I was doing more search on my own question and I wasn't surprise that I found it in the search results.

But I also found this one http://www.qandasystem.info/unix/how-to-install-subversion-1-6-x-on-sle11/

What is http://www.qandasystem.info/ about? Is that ok with SE?

What is purpose for such website?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers/48962

Comment: Already reported on the main meta: [Report sites that use SE content without following attribution rules here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/131884#131884)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This site is scraping content from Stack Exchange sites illegally (it does not provide any attribution for the content). It hopes to draw visitors by having good content without spending any effort generating that content. Visitors view ads and thus the site owner makes money.

[Report such sites on the main meta.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here) (Use [this thread instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-se-content-copiers-here) for sites with a high Google rank that respect the [attribution requirements](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), and are therefore legal.) This one has [already been reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/131884#131884).